# What is the best way to calculate number of characters in html dom node (in document node using javascript rangy library)

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview, rangy

What is the best way to calculate number of characters in html dom node (in document node using javascript rangy library)

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get text without tags you can use Jsoup library. You can make it like below

```
Jsoup.parse(html).text().length
```